# MySQL aes_encrypt padding scheme?

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes, padding

Does anyone know what padding scheme mysql uses for their aes_encrypt?

I've done a lot of googling, and all I found was "byte padding". But that's too general!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data padding is done per RFC3369/PKCS#5.  Keys are zero padded.  Unfortunately, neither of these are documented, but I got the information from this bug report:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=16713

Comment: Interesting. Technically, since AES has 128 bit blocks, it would be PKCS7.

Comment: Sorry, but is it RFC3369 or is it PKCS5? I'm trying to implement a client side (using java's Cipher) So I need a specific name for the padding schemes. Thanks!

Comment: @One - Not sure to be honest, I just pulled the info from that bug request.  I'd say try both and see which one works.

Comment: RFC3369 and PKCS5 are names describing the same thing, padded bytes are filed with the numeric value of the size of the padded space. In java that would be PKCS5Padding.

Comment: Weird, in C# for AES there is no PKCS5.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [good explanation with code that demonstrates how the padding works](http://polarssl.org/trac/wiki/MysqlAesEncryption).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what padding is being used, then decrypt with "NoPadding".  Have a look at what has been added to the end of the last block, and that will tell you what padding style is being used.

Comment: I dont think you can specify "no padding" with mysql's aes_decrypt(...)

Answer (score 1):

This answer put me on the right track:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19692724

So it really is PKCS7, as Marcus Adams noted as well.

Hope this helps someone.