# AES encryption method equivalent to MySQL aes_encrypt() function

Tags: java, mysql, encryption, aes

I want to write an AES encryption method that should be equivalent to mysql `aes_encrypt`.

I try to write but it's not correct, because mysql is nor giving proper data.

What should I do to get it correct?

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec); 
byte[] encryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(message .getBytes("UTF-8")); 
String k = new String(encryptedTextBytes); 
System.out.println("KKKKK"+k);
```

Comment: Please begin by posting your current code that doesn't work.

Comment: Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
    
    byte[] encryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(message
    .getBytes("UTF-8"));
    
    String k = new String(encryptedTextBytes);
    System.out.println("KKKKK"+k);

Comment: @user2888996 In future edit your question to add additional details such as code. I've added it for you this time.

Comment: Thanks, i am new here, don't know how to post properly. in future i will  remember

Comment: It would be really useful to have example data from your MySQL database. Can you supply example outputs? E.g. a known key value, a plaintext value and the corresponding ciphertext?

Comment: `String k = new String(encryptedTextBytes)` is incorrect. The output of an AES cipher is not character data (it is, ideally, indistinguishable from random data) and is unlikely to represent valid UTF-8 code points. If you'd like to store the ciphertext as a `String` you should encode the byte array as Base64 or Hex.

Answer (score 11):

MySQL's implementation of AES gives headaches to a lot of people. It'a mainly because of how MySQL processes the encryption key. The encryption key gets broken into 16-byte blocks and MySQL will XOR the bytes from one block with the bytes in the preceding block. If the user provided key happens to be less than 16 bytes in length then the key is essentially padded with null bytes to get up to 16 bytes. That's how the key is processed by MySQL's aes_encrypt().

The value which is to be encrypted is also processed, by padding the data using PKCS7. You can learn all about PKCS7 @ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#PKCS7 but all it does is pad the input data so it's in 16-byte blocks. The byte the data gets padded with is equivalent to the number of padding bytes that will be added.

Long story short you need process the encryption key the way MySQL does and also pad your input data using PKCS7.

Refer to the following post by Michael Simmons for example code in Java:
http://info.michael-simons.eu/2011/07/18/mysql-compatible-aes-encryption-decryption-in-java/

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this several years ago using BouncyCastle. As stated in Alen Puzic's answer the two issues are the mysql key generation and the PKCS7 padding. BouncyCastle will handle the padding for you with their `PaddedBufferedBlockCipher` but you will need to generate the key yourself. Here is the code to do that:

```
/**
 * Use password to generate a MySQL AES symmetric key
 * @param passwd Password String to use.
 * @param keyLength Must be evenly divisible by 8.
 * @return Key for use with MySQL AES encrypt/decrypt fuctions.
 */
public static KeyParameter getMySqlAESPasswdKey(String passwd, int keyLength) {
    byte[] pword = passwd.getBytes();
    byte[] rawKey = new byte[keyLength/8];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < pword.length; i++, j++) {

        if(j==rawKey.length) {
            j = 0;
        }
        rawKey[j] = pword[i];
    }

    return new KeyParameter(rawKey);
}
```

Note that the default `keyLength` for mysql is 128.

Using the above method to generate the `KeyParameter` you can complete an encryption/decryption with the following.

```
/**
 * Password based encryption using AES with MySql style key generation.
 * @param toEncrypt Unencrypted byte array.
 * @param key A KeyParameter generated with the getMySqlAESPasswdKey() method.
 * @return Encrypted byte array.
 * @throws InvalidCipherTextException If provided key cannot be used with this method on the provided data.
 */
public static byte[] mysqlAesPasswdEncrypt (byte [] toEncrypt, KeyParameter key) throws InvalidCipherTextException {
    BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new AESFastEngine());

    cipher.init(true, key);
    byte[] result = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(toEncrypt.length)];
    int len = cipher.processBytes(toEncrypt, 0, toEncrypt.length, result, 0);
    cipher.doFinal(result, len);
    return result;
}

/**
 * Password based decryption using AES with MySql style key generation.
 * @param toDecrypt Encrypted byte array.
 * @param key A KeyParameter generated with the getMySqlAESPasswdKey() method.
 * @return Unencrypted byte array.
 * @throws InvalidCipherTextException If provided key cannot be used with this method on the provided data.
 */
public static byte[] mysqlAesPasswdDecrypt (byte [] toDecrypt, KeyParameter key) throws InvalidCipherTextException {
    BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new AESFastEngine());

    cipher.init(false, key);
    byte[] result = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(toDecrypt.length)];
    int len = cipher.processBytes(toDecrypt, 0, toDecrypt.length, result, 0);
    cipher.doFinal(result, len);
    return stripTrailingZeros(result);
}

/**
 * Strip trailling zeros from the end of decrypted byte arrays.
 * @param data Data to strip.
 * @return Stripped data.
 */
public static byte[] stripTrailingZeros(byte[] data) {
    int lastData = data.length-1;
    for (int i = data.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(data[i]!=(byte)0) {
            lastData = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    byte[] data2 = new byte[lastData+1];
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, data2, 0, lastData+1);
    return data2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the insight, finally get it right, here's a simple python version:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding
import codecs


def encrypt(data, key):
    key = key + b"\0" * (16 - len(key) % 16)
    padder = padding.PKCS7(128).padder()
    data = padder.update(data) + padder.finalize()
    alg = algorithms.AES(key)
    cipher = Cipher(alg, modes.ECB(), default_backend())
    encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
    ct = encryptor.update(data) + encryptor.finalize()
    return ct


if __name__ == '__main__':
    enc = encrypt(b'123456', b'1234567890')
    print(codecs.encode(enc, 'hex'))
```

Comment: This is not giving the same output as Mysql 8.0.17 atleast.
Also the way you are creating the key might not be right. Example it doesn't work for this key
bytearray.fromhex('F3229A0B371ED2D9441B830D21A390C3F3229A0B371ED2D9441B830D21A390C3')

Comment: @arman, I think this is just missing the XOR step mentioned in [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19692724/952932), which is only needed for keys of length greater than 16 bytes

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using [the Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) Java crypto APIs. BC is widely regarded as a great crypto toolkit and it can plugin to the Java API as a crypto provider if you want. I know that doesn't directly answer your question, but I've never seen anyone have problems with Bouncy Castle.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to down-vote this. As you admit, this isn't an answer to the question. I'm sure BouncyCastle could be used once the problem is identified, but the same is probably true for many JCE providers (including the Oracle ones...)