# AES_DECRYPT not working on linux : maybe linked to Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, aes, environment

I have encrypted data in my database, and I am trying to execute a request which allows me to display in phpmyadmin the values in clear.

I use the following request :

```
 SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(`my_encrypted_colum`, UNHEX('pass_in_hexa') AS CHAR) AS clear_value 
 FROM `my_table`
```

When I use it on the dev environment (windows), it is **working well**. But once I use it on the pre-prod environment (linux), I get **NULL** for all values instead.

I am pretty sure it has something to do with the different environments, but I cannot figure out what. I don't even know which function does not act as expected : UNHEX or AES_DECRYPT (my guess would be UNHEX)?

Here are the config of my dev and preprod environments :

**Dev** :

```
Serveur : localhost via TCP/IP
Type de serveur : MySQL
Version du serveur : 5.6.15-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Version du protocole : 10
Utilisateur : root@localhost
Jeu de caractères du serveur : UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Apache/2.2.25 (Win32) PHP/5.3.19
Version du client de base de données : libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev -     20102224 - $Id: 65fe78e70ce53d27a6cd578597722950e490b0d0 $
Extension PHP : mysqli
```

**Preprod** :

```
Serveur: Localhost via UNIX socket
Logiciel: MySQL
Version du logiciel: 5.6.14 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Version du protocole: 10
Utilisateur: root@localhost
Jeu de caractères du serveur: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Version du client de base de données: libmysql - 5.1.72
Extension PHP: mysqli
```

**EDIT** :

I have continued my researches, and it seams the methods AES_DECRYPT and UNHEX are **not guilty**.
Indeed, if I directly add encrypted value in the table from phpMyAdmin as follows :

```
 INSERT INTO `my_table` (`my_encrypted_column`) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('blabla', UNHEX('pass_in_hexa'))
```

Then I manage to retrieve the data **correctly** with the previous SELECT request.

That means the problem must come from the way I insert the data in the first place.
For this I use **Hibernate** and the nullSafeSet method.

What is bothering me is : if there is a problem with the way I save the data, how come it is **working on Windows but not on Linux**?

Below are my implementations of nullSafeSet and nullSafeGet

```
private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES";

// nullSafeSet
protected void noNullSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor si) throws SQLException {
    byte[] clearText = ((String) value).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    try {
        Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
        encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getKey(cle));
        st.setBytes(index, encryptCipher.doFinal(clearText));
    } 
    catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("should never happen", e);
    }
}

@Override
public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SessionImplementor si, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    byte[] bytes = rs.getBytes(names[0]);
    try {
        Cipher decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
        decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getKey(cle));
        if (bytes != null) {
            return new String(decryptCipher.doFinal(bytes), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        } 
        else {
            return new String();
        }

    } 
    catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Mauvaise clé");
    }
}

private static SecretKeySpec getKey(String secretKey) {
    final byte[] finalKey = new byte[16];
    int i = 0;
    for (byte b : secretKey.getBytes()) {
        // XOR
        finalKey[i++ % 16] ^= b;
    }
    return new SecretKeySpec(finalKey, "AES");
}
```

Do you have any idea what might cause the problem?

Comment: What's the schema of `my_table`?

Comment: my_table has a my_encrypted_colum column of longblob type.

Comment: Some codeSamples from nullSafeGet and nullSafeSet would be usefull.

Comment: @flo I added them in my post

Comment: @realUser404 does the retrieval work by java code or is it also yielding null-values?

Comment: In the app everything is working fine whatever the server. Only the mysql request doesn't work when in linux environment (as far as it seems)

Comment: Just to narrow the possibilities: if you insert on Linux and later retrieve also on Linux, the problem also shows?

Comment: Yes the data in the database using linux server comes from normal usage on the linux server

Comment: @realUser404 are you using the same passphrase-length on windows and linux?

Comment: @flo I am using different passwords, does it matter?

Comment: @realUser404 I explained/linked it in my answer. The length may matter as mysql maybe reduces the key differently to the 128 bit AES key when the length of the password exeeds 8 chars/bytes (128 bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally managed to point out where the problem was.

At application launch, I was storing the key in a Configuration object. The key was stored as a String, doing `String cle = new String(key.getEncoded());`

This is working fine on windows and returning me following key :

```
*£Ðtôµ•Ã
```

But on linux the special characters were not cast correctly

```
*��t����
```

That was causing the encryption/decryption to be done with wrong key on linux, so then I could not use the "correct" key value when doing a "SELECT" in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have a chaining/padding difference between your systems due to not setting them explicitly. Try

```
private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding";
```

for getting your Cipher instance as it should be the implementation MySql uses as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417250/mysql-aes-encrypt-padding-scheme).

If you have a passphrase longer than 8 chars (bytes), mysql uses its own implementation of generating a AES 128 bit key from it as suggested 
[here](http://info.michael-simons.eu/2011/07/18/mysql-compatible-aes-encryption-decryption-in-java/). It maybe differs from the key Java is using when your passphrase is longer than 8 bytes.

Comment: I still haven't checked your suggestion, I will try it this weekend

Comment: I explicited the AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding, so now at least I have same result on both environments : returning NULL when I try to decrypt. Maybe it is another algorithm?

Comment: Add least it's repeatable ;-) I'm sorry, I'm out of new guesses and just recap things I would have done: Change key in pre-prod to key working on dev (with dev's working settings: "AES"). Bind dev JNDI to pre-prod database with settings working on dev's db (may reduces problem to pre-prod's java). Copy pre-prod's data to dev's db and vice versa (may reduce problem to pre-prods's sql). I still think it's a problem with the encryption mode/key (especially as a lot of other problems has been ruled out by other answers). If something new happens let me know as I'm really interessed in the reason.

Comment: Hum my bad, actually that didn't change anything, I just forgot I tried using different key on the dev environment so I thought I couldn't decrypt anymore but I was just using wrong key. So in the end specifying AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding didn't change anything, but I believe it is normal as just "AES" is supposed to be AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding by default

Comment: I think then it comes down to the key (length). Have you tried a different (shorter) key on pre-dev?

Comment: Actually I have checked : the key generated for both is 128bits

Comment: The problem is how the key is generated from your passphrase. When the passphrase is longer than 128 bit, the reduction to 128 bit may differ between java and mysql (when less than 128 bit zero-padding is used, which fills the remaining bits with 0).

Comment: Ok I see your point. The thing is I tried to switch keys : using dev key on preprod environment : I couldn't decrypt afterwards ; using preprod key on dev environment : I could decrypt. That means it is not linked to the key generation but really the way encryption is done when on the preprod environement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69569/discussion-between-flo-and-realuser404).

Answer (score 1):

check:

- if you have same data in those databases. connect from your dev to preprod db and check if it works. connect from preprod to your dev database and check if it works. this way you should narrow the problem: db vs environment
- jvm encryption permission. maybe your dev jvm can use strong encryption and preprod can't
- case sensitivity: some DBs (not sure about mysql) store tables in files. windows is case insensitive, linux is not. i've seen problems like that in the past

Comment: Ok so I have tried following : preprod data on my dev environment : cannot decrypt. dev data on my preprod environment : can decrypt. This is indeed helpful, now I know problem really comes from encryption

Comment: How can I check about strong encryption permission?

Comment: https://www.google.pl/search?q=java+jce instruction should be inside downloaded package

Answer (score 1):

You might have a character set issue.  If one of your MySQL databases is running with a latin1 character set, the insertion of UTF-8 data will result in scrambled data.

To check the character sets on the table in question, run this command on both your systems:

```
mysql> show create table foo
| foo | CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `FLD1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FLD2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FLD3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

It will show you what character set is in-use for that particular table.  If it's not UTF8, then it won't match your code and you will have data corruption problems.

If this is in fact the problem, you can change the character set by running an ALTER statement like the following:

```
ALTER TABLE foo CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Comment: Thank you but both my databases are in UTF-8

Comment: What about the jdbc URL in jdbc.properties or whereever? Is that the same on both systems?

Comment: We use jndi not jdbc. What should I look for?

Comment: Even with jndi you have to provide a url that identifies the database. This url can take parameters that affect character set handling. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html

Comment: Just to be sure you understand my problem : I cannot decrypt the data in the "linux" database with "AES_DECRYPT" but the application decrypts it just fine. That is why I believe it is not a data corruption problem but rather there is a difference in the way the encryption is done on both environment (whereas the code is of course exactly the same)